# How to print an ArrayList from a seperate method?

Tags: java, arrays, class, arraylist, methods

I'm trying to do this: If the user chooses this option, the program will print to the screen the data read in.

Sample Output:

Date: January 10, 2018 Output: 236.9 
Date: January 11, 2018 Output: 267.6 
Date: January 12, 2018 Output: 278.1

Write a method called PrintData to do this task. Choose the appropriate parameters and return type.

Once done printing, the main menu will be displayed again.

I've already read in the data to my array list in my method Upload Data, I'm now trying to figure out how to make a separate method where it prints the UploadData's Arraylist.

What I have right now won't work I don't think.

```
           : `  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    //calling menu
    showMenu();
   int userChoice=keyboard.nextInt();
    while (userChoice == 1)
    {
        UploadData();
        showMenu();
        int userchoice=keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    while(userChoice ==2)
    {

        PrintData();
        showMenu();
        int userchoice=keyboard.nextInt();
    }
}

public static void showMenu()
{
    //creating menu
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Power Plant Analyzer program. Please choose from the following options:\n"
            + " 1. Upload Data\n 2. View Data \n 3. Download Statistics \n 4. Print Month \n 5. Exit the program");

}
public static String[] UploadData() throws IOException
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Asking for file
    System.out.println("What is the name of the file that contains the data?");
    String inputFileName=keyboard.nextLine();
   //creating file
    File f = new File(inputFileName);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(f);

    //creating arraylist
    ArrayList<Entry> MonthList = new ArrayList<>();
    //reading the file
    while(inputFile.hasNext())
    {
        //read a line
        String m = inputFile.next();
        String d = inputFile.next();
        String y = inputFile.next();
        float p = inputFile.nextFloat();

        //create Entry with info read in
        Entry i = new Entry(m,d,y,p);
        //add it to the arraylist
        MonthList.add(i);

    }
    //print Entry's into arraylist
    //for(int i =0; i <MonthList.size(); i++)
        //MonthList.get(i).print();
    return null;

}
public static void PrintData(ArrayList<Entry> MonthList)
{
    for(int i =0; i <MonthList.size(); i++)
        MonthList.get(i).print();


    //ArrayList<Entry> MonthList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList());
    //int pos = Collections.binarySearch(MonthList);

}
```

}`

```
  //declaring variables
private String month;
private String day;
private String year;
private float powerOutput;

//Constructors
public Entry(){}

public Entry (String m, String d, String y, float p)
{
    month = m;
    day =d;
    year =y;
    powerOutput=p;
}
//creating print to call ArrayList in main
public void print()
{
    System.out.println("Month: " + month + " Day: " + day + " Year: " + year + " Power Output: " + powerOutput);
}
```

}

Comment: Unrelated: try to use meaninful names, even parameter names deserve more than m d y p. And: follow java conventions consistently. Methods go camelCase(), so dont do some camelCase() and some UpperCase().

Comment: For this line in my main:  PrintData(); I'm getting an error "method PrintData in class Project cannot be applied to given types: required: ArrayList<Entry>

Comment: is `MonthList` a static declared item?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure but I think so

Answer (score 0):

In your uploadData method, make it return a `List<Entry>` (instead of String[] which you are not even returning) , so instead of `return null;` , do `return MonthList;` Also change its signature to :

```
public static List<Entry> UploadData() throws IOException {
```

Then in your main method code, add the declaration of this and use it accordingly with your UploadData and PrintData methods :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<Entry> MonthList = null;
    ...

    while (userChoice == 1)
    {
        MonthList = UploadData();
        showMenu();
        int userchoice=keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    while(userChoice ==2)
    {

        PrintData(MonthList);
        showMenu();
        int userchoice=keyboard.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: I changed the method to: public static List<Entry> UploadData() throws IOException but I'm getting symbol not found under List

Comment: Okay, this is my first coding class so I admit I'm bit of a noob, it's an overwhelming topic at some points and my professor speeds through some chapters so I'm def behind on reading. I'm having an issue with the actual outcome, if I enter 2 it asks for the inputFile again and then doesn't print anything. I think there's a problem with my while loop?

Comment: I changed them to if statements and if the user chooses 2 it doesn't print anything and the program stops, is it because of this line? ArrayList<Entry> MonthList =null;

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a class exercise so I won't write a solution for you, but I'll try giving you some tips to point you in the right direction

1) You can't directly access the arraylist created in method `UploadData()` because it's a local variable. Given your description asks you to 'Choose the appropriate parameters and return type' you should return the 'MonthList' from `UploadData()` instead of null.
[Note: You may have to add the MonthList result to another List in your main class, since you call this method in a while loop]

2) Your method `PrintData()` takes `ArrayList<Entry> MonthList` as a parameter, but in your main method you are trying to call it without passing in any arguments. Have an ArrayList in your main method that you pass into the call

Hope this helps